# Getting back to Ubuntu from Chrome on Pixel chromebook

Tags: dual-boot, chromebook

I installed Ubuntu via `crouton` on my Pixel but now after turning computer off I can't figure out how to get back to Ubuntu. I tried ctrl-alt-shift and back but it isn't working now.
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Crouton doesn't give you your typical duel-boot environment, but instead creates a "chroot" environment that allows you to run both Chrome OS + Ubuntu (or another distro) simultaneously, without rebooting your computer.

You should be able to switch between the two environments via a keyboard shortcut:

- Chrome OS <-> Ubuntu
  Press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Back`
- If this fails, try:
  `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Forward`, followed by `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Refresh`
- For Chromebooks running on an ARM processor, to swap between the two environments use:
  `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `Back` and `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `Forward`

If the keyboard shortcut still fails, you can try opening a Chrome OS terminal, then typing `shell` into the command line, followed by `sudo startunity`.